# Is Android vulnerable to the BlueBorne attack found in Linux?

Tags: security, ota-update

I recently discovered there's an attack called BlueBorne against the Linux bluetooth functionality: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392001/how-to-secure-linux-systems-against-the-blueborne-remote-attack

If I'm using an Android system with a bluetooth keyboard, should I be worried, considering that Android is based on the Linux kernel? Do I need to patch all Android systems in use with an over-the-air update to fix the vulnerability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Android device with a patch level prior to September 1st 2017 will be vulnerable, yes. Google patched this vulnerability in the September 1st update which has been released for Nexus and Pixel devices. Other devices will need to wait until the manufacturer releases an update containing these fixes.

An [official test app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.armis.blueborne_detector) has been released to the Play Store which you can use to test whether your device is vulnerable.

[Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/13/googles-september-security-patch-fixes-blueborne-bluetooth-vulnerability/)